Requesting for the Reference of multiplicative Property for Resultants
I have learned the definition of the Resultant of two polynomials Resultant of two polynomials. Following this definition, I want to see the proof of one property described in the "Characterizing properties" section in the above link.
Formally, my question is,
if $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ are polynomial in $R[x]$, where $R$ is any commutative ring, then
Res$(f(x)g(x),h(x) =$ Res$(f(x),h(x))$Res$(g(x),h(x))$.
I am kindly asking for a reference for the above property. I could not find any mention of these results in the references listed on the Wikipedia page (Gelfand Kapranov Zelevinski; Cox Little O'Shea; Macaulay; Salmon). Or maybe this reference is too Abstract for me to understand. Is there any proof using the basic definition of resultant?
I have seen a Similar Question but don't understand it clearly. Is it possible to give a more detailed solution? Or can we do the same proof in my setting, where I am assuming my $f,g \in R[x]$, where $R$ is a commutative ring?

Yes, I saw this; I did not understand the proof, and I don't know if it is true for any commutative ring; maybe I have to update my question a bit.

Since the equality is of integer polynomials (in the coefficients of $f$, $g$ and $h$), they hold over any ring.
